# Deleting child headings that don't have body text below

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to delete empty child headings which are in word document by using vba but i tried with some vba macro where it is deleting all the headings without having data irrespective of hierarchy level but we want to delete child headings which are empty.

If some content is available at 3rd level then it should keep above two level headings also for the same.

Can someone help on the same how to start with this by using vba

**Input:**

1. Test Data (U)

1.1 Requirements

1.1.1   Test Requirements

1.1.1.1 Safety

1.1.1.1.1 Voltage incl. Monitoring

1.2    New Requirements

1.2.1 New test requirements

Test data which is used to write requirements

**Output:**

1. Test Data (U)

1.1    New Requirements

1.1.1 New test requirements

Test data which is used to write requirements

```
Sub CleanupHeadings()

    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim pNext As Paragraph

    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If IsHeading(p) Then
            ' check the following paragraph
            Set pNext = p.Next
            If Not pNext Is Nothing Then
                If IsHeading(pNext) Then
                    ' next paragraph is a heading too, so delete current paragraph
                    p.Range.Delete
                End If
            Else
                ' no following paragraph, i.e. document ends with a heading
                p.Range.Delete
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

```
Function IsHeading(para As Paragraph) As Boolean

    IsHeading = para.OutlineLevel < wdOutlineLevelBodyText

End Function
```

we tried with above code where it is deleting all headings without having any content irrespective of level of heading

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function:

```vb
Private Function hasChildText(p As Paragraph) As Boolean

If p.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
    'we are at the lowest level
    hasChildText = p.Range.Characters.Count > 1
ElseIf p.Next Is Nothing Then
    'last para and no body text
    hasChildText = False
ElseIf p.Next.OutlineLevel = wdOutlineLevelBodyText Then
    'next para is text
    hasChildText = p.Next.Range.Characters.Count > 1
ElseIf p.Next.OutlineLevel < p.OutlineLevel Then
    'end of level hierarchy
    hasChildText = False
Else
    'this is the recursive part
    hasChildText = hasChildText(p.Next)
End If

End Function
```

You call it like this:

```vb
Sub CleanupHeadings()

    Dim p As Paragraph
    Dim pNext As Paragraph

    For Each p In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If hasChildText(p) = False Then
            p.Range.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: The flaw in the `hasChildText` function is that it takes no account of whether the Body Text paragraph contains any text. The OP wants to delete headings that are not followed by body level text. `hasChildText` returns true even if the body text paragraph contains no text.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt - that's right - I updated the code to count the characters of a para

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with this code and it is not deleting one level above heading but we need above parent as well since hierarchy should be 1, 1.1, 1.1.1

Comment: What style has the paragraph that doesn't get deleted?

Comment: Thanks for update but still it is not working and it is ending with up Run Time error as cannot edit range and i am not able to keep the image here.                                                                Exact error message: Run-time error '5904'  Cannot edit range

Comment: Pretty hard to analyze w/o knowing your document ... What image? Is the document locked?

Comment: I meant the error image to attach here. Issue is showing that """Cannot edit range""" at "p.Range.Delete" in the main function CleanupHeadings(). My document is having many headings which are empty at different levels and it is document of 90 pages